# randomly pick an element from a list in python using pseudo random generator which should happen 50 percent of time

Tags: python, random, probability

I have a list which has certain elements.For example event=["head","tail"].Each element should be picked randomly using pseudo random generator.This random event should occur roughly 50 percent of time.Use some sort of pseudo random number generator, but make this in a way that we can repeat the test or the sequence that way if something in the test fails, we can repeat what happened.This should be implemented in python

Comment: What do you mean with:
1) random event 50% ? Do you mean heads and tails should be called the same amount of times?
2)repeating; do you mean doing the test two times results in the same sequence?

Comment: Yes Head and tail should occur same amount of times.So if at all test fails I want to check how it failed.But I can only know only when I know the sequence in which an event occurs right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!Instead of h and t can I replace it with two functions?I want to call those two functions randomly.Will that be possible?@JeD

Comment: Yeah, that should not be a problem, since we only choose the index randomly. @Sai

Comment: What If I want to get head and tail consequently?I mean first if it picks up head,next time it should pick up tail,so on....this should happen 6 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random as rnd
coin=["h","t"]
seed=10
rnd.seed(seed)

for i in range(100):
    print coin[rnd.randint(0,1)]
```

Is this what you want? Please be more specific in future questions

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you mean by

> make this in a way that we can repeat the test or the sequence that way if something in the test fails, we can repeat what happened

is the use of seeds. Seeds are essentially strings that cause the pseudorandom number generator to always produce the same results, provided the same seed.

```
import random
random.seed('abcd')

coin = ['heads', 'tails']
number_of_tests = 100

for i in range(number_of_tests):
    print(random.choice(coin))
```

And any time you want to repeat the test with the same results, just call

```
random.seed('abcd')
```

again.

Comment: So here it chooses heads or tails randomly.What is the meaning of abcd?How it is related to heads and tails?@JeD

Comment: @Sai 'abcd is a so called *"seed-value"* the random function needs a starting point. I use `10` as starting point, he uses `'abcd'`. This is done to make sure that we get the same result even when running it several times. 
If you change the seed value you get a different random series.

Comment: Thanks!!That was useful.